# Natural Language Processing. Where to start?

Tags: ai.artificial-intel, string-search

Natural Language Processing is an area which interests me. I know little about it and I'm hoping somebody can suggest a starting point. Basically I'd like to develop a search algorithm specific for natural languages. One that deals with ambiguities in an intelligent fashion. Where would be a great starting point? Can anyone recommend some good papers or other resources to help me get started?

Comment: Natural language processing isn't really cstheory AFAIK.  Why not try http://metaoptimize.com/qa/ ?

Comment: There also is a NLP proposal on StackExchange: http://bit.ly/u4lZUG